# How to execute multiple sql scripts against firebird

Tags: sql, firebird, flyway

I know flyway and it works nice but it does not support firebird datases. What is a workaround to execute multiple `.sql` scripts in a certain order against a firebird database?

Comment: See https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/441

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad and basically boils down to a request for tool suggestions, which is off-topic. In any case, you could look at Liquibase.

Answer (score -1):

TASK SCHEDULER (.bat file that executes SQL file)